# jQuery scrolling to a certain point on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

At my page, i have a few booleans in my script, to check if the first screen is activated, and the same thing for the second screen. Screen 1 fills up the whole screen.

It looks something like this:

```
var headerLoaded = true,
    contentLoaded = false;
```

When i scroll, i want the page to scroll automaticly to the 'content' area of my webpage. And i had this code for it:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (($(window).scrollTop() > 0) && (!contentLoaded && headerLoaded)) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top
        }, 500, function() {
            contentLoaded = true;
            headerLoaded = false;
        });
    }
});
```

It checks if im not at the top of the page, and for the 2 booleans.

The function works great, but it's still calling the

```
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top
        }, 500, function() {
            contentLoaded = true;
            headerLoaded = false;
        });
```

part when  i'm scrolled down to the 'content' div.

So everytime i scroll when im at the 'content' div, its scrolling back to the top of that.

Btw, both of the div's are absolute.

Comment: Food for thought: hijacking the scroll event to animate page scrolling is bad UX (according to some intelligent people). http://trentwalton.com/2013/10/23/scroll-hijacking/
https://news.layervault.com/stories/9138-on-scroll-hijacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the animate is calling your original `$(window).scroll(...)` over and over.

Try telling your main `scroll` listener not to start animating if its already animating.

```
var animating = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (!animating && $(window).scrollTop() > 0 && !contentLoaded && headerLoaded) {
        animating = true;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top
        }, 500, function() {
            animating = false;
            contentLoaded = true;
            headerLoaded = false;
        });
    }
});
```

wait.. i just read it..
You're just locking the screen at the content... why animate at all?

The answer I was giving was saying the animating the scroll will also trigger the main scroll, resulting in an endless loop... but what are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: Your code works btw, thank you for that. Im trying to make scroll abit nicer, when i just scrolldown once, it looks very ugly and i can still see a part of my mainscreen, wich i dont want, so i tried that? Good idea isnt it? :P @Funkodebat

Comment: so do you want the page to always be scrolled to the top of the content? If so, why have a scrollbar at all?

Comment: Because i cant disable scrolling for people right? And it's much more smooth when you make it a animation, just for one time tho. @Funkodebat

Comment: you can use css to do `body, html { overflow-y: hidden }` and they won't have a scroll bar..